# BrowserLink in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio 2013 introduced a new feature called [BrowserLink](http://vswebessentials.com/features/browserlink).

I created a sample new ASP.NET MVC project in VS 2013 and was able to use the BrowserLink feature, which worked as expected.

[image: Connection Link Created]

[image: Dynamic Script Created]

So I wanted to replicate the same in my existing project using Visual Studio Premium 2013. But it won't work as expected. The number of connections is zero. I've cross verified with [this link](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link) but it still won't work.

[image: Connection Link Not Created]
[image]

A few things to note:

- Refresh Linked Browser ( Ctr + Alt + Enter ) **always disabled**
- **No Connections** in Browser Link Dashboard
- Run application and view Source on any page , **Visual studio not creating**

  ```
      {
       "appName":"Interne Explorer","requestId":"ecd0d25f2912471a8489c3faffe20e93"
      }
  ```

which in turn feels it's not able to create browserlink dynamic script.

Answer (score 0):

Well i am not sure what type of project it is not working in as you do not specify. However you can tweek browserlink in your webconfig file

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
     <add name="Browser Link for HTML" path="*.html" verb="*"
       type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
       resourceType="File" preCondition="integratedMode" />
   </handlers>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

So whatever your ending paths are. html aspx just change in the *path=*

If this does not work . Make sure you have the correct build . There are a different versions for different visual studio builds. So vs2013 update 2 has a different install to vs2013

Comment: Background of my project is combination of classic asp, asp.net & MVC application. We are using framework 4.5.1 & MVC 5

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using though?

Comment: visual studio premium 2013

Comment: but which update? The latest version is currently update 4. You need to make sure the update version corresponds to the web essentials version https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/releases

Comment: Version 12.0 Update 4.